# How to generate a 4-digit validation code according to latitude & longitude information?

Tags: algorithm, hash

My application needs this feature:

1. User A can upload his location information and get ADD CODE which is
   generated on server.
2. User B can input ADD CODE and also has to upload his location
   information. Only when userA and userB is close enough and ADD CODE
   is matched can they finally be friends.
3. Before calculating distance and comparing ADD CODE, I will check
   whether their city number(unique for each city) is same. In other
   words, I have to make sure that in each city, ADD CODE won't
   conflict with another at the same time(or few minutes).

   Of course, a 4-digit number won't satisfy all possibilities, but is there a way to generate this 4-digit number to satisfy this feature as much as possible?

Comment: The code does not need to be connected to the location in any way, just by unique. Am I correct?  Well if you just want to make sure there are no conflicts, you can use `factory design pattern` in your server. That way you can control on which code is created.

Comment: What happens when user B inputs ADD CODE of user C instead of A?

Comment: @domen That’s why I have to check whether their city code is same and make sure the ADD CODE won’t conflict with another one in the same city, assuming the number of users who uses this service at the same time is fewer than 10000.

Comment: You haven't really answered. :) What I'm thinking is accidentally wrong ADD CODE (can be disruptive is this service grows; my city has 10mil inhabitants for example), and also intentionally wrong (someone just brute forcing 10000 of them, potentially adding all friends in the area, repeatedly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this sequence happens within a limited period of time (and not that an Add code is valid for all-time):

Your 4-digit number doesn't need to be globally unique, it only needs to be unique within this window of time. So, with that observation, maintain a table of Add codes, when they were issued and for what location. Generate them randomly ensuring they aren't already in the table. Periodically remove any Add codes that have expired.

Provided you never have more than 10,000 users simultaneously trying to connect with each other this will work.

If you need more than that consider allowing duplicates in the table but using the lat/long to ensure that the same Add code is never allocated to any point within 2x the max distance allowed for pairing.

Comment: Simple and effective!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to generate this 4-digit number to satisfy this feature as much as possible?

Yes. There are probably millions of possible ways to generate a 4-digit number (where almost all of them are awful and don't satisfy most of the requirements); and if you sort them in order of how much they satisfy, then one of them must satisfy the feature as much as possible.

The real question is, how awful and unsatisfactory would "as much as possible" be?

If you assume 4 decimal digits; then you're limited to 10000 locations or 10000 unique users. That's unlikely to be enough for anything good.

If you assume 4 hexadecimal digits; then you're limited to 65536 locations or 65536 unique users. That's better but still not enough.

So.. what if you used "base 1234567"? In this case a 4-digit number has 2323050529221952581345121 permutations. The surface of the Earth is about 510.1 million square kilometers, so this would be enough to encode a location very precisely (probably within a few meters?).

Comment: Thanks for providing this clue!